# Cut off frequency of low pass filter

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have a data [here](https://pastebin.com/GMRCxuXk), I want to make sense of Lowpass filtering function in Mathematica.I do not fully understand units of cut off frequency in this option since the data is in frequency space. What I would like to do is to eliminate the small oscillation. It turns out that the Lowpass filter is doing its job

I have done the following.

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

and secondly,

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], 
   LowpassFilter[data[[All, 2]], 0.1]}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Frequency (Hz)", "Scaled intensity with offset correction"}]
```

[image]

Here; what is the unit of the cut off frequency which is "0.1".

I know that I should define a sample rate in order to know the cut-off frequency. But from the definition of Lowpass filtering, I saw that the sample rate is automatically defined.

Could anyone please explain me how do I make sense of the cut-off frequency 0.1 and its unit in this example?

Comment: As mentioned in the **Details and Options** section of document of `LowpassFilter`, "By default, `SampleRate->1` is assumed for images as well as lists. "

Comment: Is your data given as a time series or as amplitudes/power for specific frequencies?

Comment: I ask because `LowpassFilter[]` expects time series data. If your data is given already in the frequency domain you usually just multiply your spectrum by the filter frequency response.

Comment: This data is Intensity (arb units) as a function of frequency space. What I want to do is to eliminate the small oscillation in frequency space. I also want to know what is the cut off (in units) for that.

Comment: @TM90, the argument of your function is not the same frequency as used in `LowpassFilter`. It operates with let's say the spatial frequency which is derived from the Fourier[<yourdata>] counts. This is a normalized number of counts that is enough for smooth representation of your spectrum. The full number of counts is a length of your data list.

Comment: @Rom38, Do you mean to say that sample rate-> Length(data)?

Comment: @TM90, no the `SampleRate->1` means that length of the `Fourier` image of the <data> is the same as length of the <data>. The cut-off freq = 0.1 means, I guess, that amplitudes of the first 10% of counts will be used for formation of the filtered signal and all the highest will be set to zero. You can compare the result of the `LowpassFilter` with hand-made `Fourier` filter working by the described logic.

Comment: @Rom38, Could you give me  some reference where some one does in Mathematica

Comment: Well, I think my comment above has answered your question, which part do you still have difficulty in understanding?

Comment: If you want to know the physical units of the LowpassFilter, you need to be clear on the physical units of your data. You label the vertical axis "Intensity", but this is nonsense since intensity is watts per square metre https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_(physics) and hence is always positive, yet you show negative values. Your horizontal axis is also suspicious, since you only show a very small part of the frequency axis. You need to describe the meaning of the data in order to know the meaning of the operations carried out on it.

Comment: @bills, Sure Intensity is always positive. That is why I mentioned that it is some arbitrary units with an offset corrected, my apologies for the details The horizontal axis is frequency, there is no doubt in that. In order to do Fourier transform and inverse, I do not think you need full data.

Comment: Here's what you need at a minimum: how many samples are there in your data per unit of the horizontal axis (frequency, in your case). Usually in a time based filtering, this is samples per second. In your case, you need to specify number of samples per Hz.

Comment: Since your data is in frequency units, the cut off frequency for LowPassFilter will be in time units. Specifically, since your data is intensities, the cut off will refer to a cut off lag in the autocorrelation function of the amplitude time series behind your intensities. But does that actually mean anything in the context of your problem? If you want to smooth this data, I'd suggest using `MovingAverage`: at least it will be clear what you're doing. Or you could do some kind of fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After downloading your data, you can see that the sampling rate is:

```
sr = (Max[data[[All, 1]]] - Min[data[[All, 1]]])/(Length[data] - 1)
400
```

where sr is in "Hz per sample." This is 1/400 samples per Hz, so when you are choosing the parameter 0.1 for the LowpassFilter, you are selecting a filter with about 1/(0.1/400) = 4000 Hz bandwidth. To check this, make a time series object and lowpassfilter it:

```
tsData = TimeSeries[data];
ListPlot[LowpassFilter[tsData, 0.1/400]]
```

[image]

Observe that this is identical to your original filtered output given by

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], LowpassFilter[data[[All, 2]], 0.1]}]]
```

Comment: Awesome,  Thank you very much bill s, Now I got you.

Comment: Er… I think the bandwidth should be `0.1/(1/400)/(2 Pi)`?